# Meaning of could

Tags: sentence-meaning

Sometimes I don't understand the meaning of "could " .

***The situation is bad, but it could be worse.***

In this case what is the meaning of the could ?

1-It might be worse(there is a possiblity to be worse )

2-There was a possibility to be worse (but ıt didn't happen)

If the meaning is "1" .Why did we use "but" instead of "and" , "but" looks awkward normally after the "but" we say the opposite of what we have just said .

And ıf the meaning is "2" why don't we say "this situation is bad , but it could have beeen worse "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 is correct, though what you have in brackets is implicit not explicit. As to why you don't have "have been" this is because of agreement of tense/aspect with the "is" in "The situation is bad".

Comment: How can we know 1 is not correct ?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden The first scenario can't be correct because it's already stated that the situation *is* bad—not worse. We know for a fact that it *isn't* worse.

Comment: Note that you can say both *could be worse* and *could have been worse* and be completely understood either way. There may be a subtle difference in meaning, but it's almost always lost in actual communication. For all intents and purposes, they express the same thing. Idiomatic use aside, however, and from a very strict viewpoint, it *should* be *could have been* (*could have ended up*, *could have resulted in*, *could have happened differently*, and so on).